# Не получается правильно прижать div к низу страницы

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Верстаю страницу, и столкнулся с проблемой – `div.player` "плавает" при изменении ширины браузера (на картинке вы видите неприятный отступ снизу)[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Я пытался `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`, но опять проблема: в таком случае он перекрывает контент страницы. Сюда сниппет вставить не могу, так что вот на jsfiddle:

Скрипт: https://fiddle.jshell.net/2hgL54ww/419/

Режим просмотра: https://fiddle.jshell.net/2hgL54ww/419/show/

Comment: отличная работа .... есть за что поставить свой голос

Comment: @МаксимЛенский  Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делайте прям при помощи css

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Пример [вот](https://jsfiddle.net/eyqtauqk/2/)

Comment: Помогло! Правда `margin-top: -0.2%;` пришлось поставить на `.vinylwheel` из-за того, что `body` теперь flexbox.

Comment: Главное, что помогло.